# Calculating distance between coordinates

Tags: qgis, distance, coordinates

I would like to calculate the distances between a list of coordinates (classic GPS coord.). From coordinate A to B from B to C from C to D and so on, and so forth. Is there any  program, or website, or any QGIS plugin i could use? Sadly im not familiar with R. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about old good Pythagoras? C#/Java solution is as simple as :

```
double dist = Math.Sqrt((A.X - B.X)*(A.X - B.X) + (A.Y - B.Y)*(A.Y - B.Y));
```

for any coordinate system^.

Comment: There must ne some plugins here: http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/
I am pretty sure they have what you need. Also you can write formula once in Excel/Libre Office Calc and use it.

Comment: Pythagoras won't work for GPS coordinates (Assuming WGS84 lat/longs) because lat/long is an angular measurement. You'll need to use some trig to find the great-circle distance instead. The Haversine formula is quick and easy if you don't need very fine precision.

Comment: dunno, I used Pythagoras in one program 3 years ago, and noone noticed yet :)

Comment: Hi, I am also interested in this question. Specifically, I am working on a case study there the further points are at about a distance of 120 km. We were thinking about the Great Circle Distances. Can I calculate them in QGIS? Thank you.